# Which 3D object properties should be affected by distance?

Tags: 3d

Which 3D object properties should be affected by distance in VR and other 3D applications and how important is it that they are changed?
For example the level of detail, colour (?)...

Comment: Are you asking which properties should be treated differently at different distances?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant :)

Comment: It might help to edit to explain this - it took me a while to guess what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right! I tried to rephrase the question, please do tell if it's still hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one major thing that I can think of in nonstereographic view that is affected by size and that is:

- Atmospheric haze and subsurface scattering, even this is similar at most or all macroscopic ranges.

That said you can easily do this by fudging one constant in a shader. Or slightly more tediously by adding aerosols in the air if you are in fact doing this in real photography, altough getting it exactly right is hard.

This changes in stereoscopy as humans have some sense of their own scale. So the disparity between cameras sets a scale. But if you change the distance between the cameras then you change scale so even they do not have to be in absolute scale just relative scale.

So in fact most things are self similar at all practical scales. And only when you start to see effects that are fixed light wavelength do you get into this problem.